# Get Values of accelerometer Xuart

Tags: c++, fpga

I am working with a xilinx spartan 6 board and a microcontroller i use my microcontroller accelerometer to control a movingblock on my spartan 6.

I now print

```
xil_printf("%c",XUartLite_RecvByte(XPAR_UARTLITE_1_BASEADDR));
```

and i get returned in my terminal

```
$SWITCH 0
$ENC___ 13
$ACC___ -205 -317 860
$ACCRAW 796 812 1134
$SWITCH 0
$ENC___ 13
```

i just wan't my $ACCRAW data any idea how to do this and store this to use it to control my movingBlock?

Comment: Are you saying you ask for a single char to be printed and you get 6 *lines* of text?  That *is* bizarre.  The text must be coming from somewhere else!

Answer (score 0):

You need a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing).

In your case, this would be a simple state machine, with one state for each letter of the string `\n$ACCRAW` that has been recognized, i.e.

```
State 0 (uninteresting data):
    '\n'      -> go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0

State 1 (beginning of line):
    '$'       -> go to state 2
    '\n'      -> go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0

State 2 (after dollar sign):
    'A'       -> go to state 3
    '\n'      -> go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0

[...]

State 8 (after "$ACCRAW"):
    ' '       -> clear x, go to state 9
    '\n'      -> go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0
```

followed by one state for each of the three axes:

```
State 9 (read X value):
    '0'-'9'   -> multiply x by 10, add current digit
    ' '       -> clear y, go to state 10
    '\n'      -> go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0

[...]

State 11 (read Z value):
    '0'-'9'   -> multiply z by 10, add current digit
    '\n'      -> start processing of data, go to state 1
    otherwise -> go to state 0
```

In the last state, the final newline then starts processing of the new values, before going to state 1, as usual.

You can start the state machine either in state 0 or 1.